# python blocking sockets, send returns immediately

Tags: python, sockets, multithreading, blocking, send

I am writing a multithreaded socket application in Python using the socket module.
the server listens for connections and when it gets one it spawns a thread for that socket.

the server thread sends some data to the client. but the client is not yet ready to receive it. I thought this would have caused the server to wait until the client starts recv but instead returns immediately

the client then calls recv which is blocking and no data is ever received.

client socket constructor

```
self.__clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
self.__clientSocket.connect((server, port))
```

server socket constructor

```
        self.servSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.servSock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        #self.servSock.settimeout(None)
        self.servSock.setblocking(1)
        self.servSock.bind((self.addr,self.port))
        self.servSock.listen(5)
```

listening accept thread

```
    try:
        (cs, address) = self.servSock.accept()
    except socket.timeout:
        return
    threadName = '\r\nClient %s:%s\r\n' % (cs, address)
    print threadName
    clientSocketHandler = ClientSocket()
    clientSocketHandler.setClientSocket(cs)
    self.clients.newThread(self.clientFunc, {clientSocketHandler : "1"}, threadName).start()
```

server and clients send/rec methods from inside ClientSocket

```
receivedData = self.__clientSocket.recv(1024*1024)

self.__clientSocket.send(s)
```

any ideas why send() is returning straight away?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> any ideas why send() is returning straight away?

all send() does is fill the network buffer and return the ammount of bytes sent.

if you want a send that blocks just recv an acknowledgement message from the client.

Comment: so what method do i invoke to do a blocking send?

Answer (score 1):

The client doesn't have to be ready to receive data - data will queue up in the socket's receive buffer until you are ready to recv() it. Send returns instantly because the send buffer isn't full - if it was full, send() would block until there was room for the data you wanted to send.

Most of the time you'll never fill it - hence what you are experiencing. On a side, you probably don't want a recv call with 1024*1024 in it - that's a little on the high side.

Comment: i need some sort of a blocking send method that will not return until the client receives it.
i have been experimenting with sendall and calling recv after a send at which point the client will recv and then send to unblock

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about the delay i fixed the problem shortly after asking this question. @Lee thanks for your answer it pointed me in the right direction.
the solution was to send a 4byte int specifying the size of the data to follow. the client would always receive these four bytes and then the size of the data.

```
from commandClass import Command
from commandActionClass import CommandAction
import socket
from time import *
import struct

class ClientSocket():
    instance = None
    __connected = False
    __clientSocket = None

    @staticmethod
    def getInstance():
        if ClientSocket.instance == None:
            ClientSocket.instance = ClientSocket()
        return ClientSocket.instance

    def __init__(self):
        self.__connected = False
        self.receivedData = ''
        self.bufSize = 4096
        self.buffer = ''

    def connect(self, server, port):
        if self.isConnected():
            raise Exception('Already connected.')

        self.__clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.__clientSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
        self.__clientSocket.connect((server, port))
        self.__clientSocket.setblocking(1)
        self.__connected = True

    def disconnect(self):
        try:
            self.receivedData = ''
            self.buffer = ''
            self.__clientSocket.close()
        except Exception, e:
            print e
        finally:
            self.__connected = False

    def sendString(self,s):
        try:
            if (self.isConnected()):
                self.__clientSocket.send(s)
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            self.disconnect()

    def __pop(self, size):
        data = self.receivedData[:size]
        self.receivedData = self.receivedData[size:]
        return data

    def __recv(self,toRead):
        self.flush()
        while ((len(self.receivedData)<toRead)and(self.isConnected())):
            data = self.__clientSocket.recv(self.bufSize)
            if not data:
                self.disconnect()
            self.receivedData = self.receivedData + data

        return self.__pop(toRead)

    def __sendint(self, x):
        self.__sendall(struct.pack("i", x))

    def __recvint(self):
        data = self.__recv(4)
        if not data:
            raise Exception('Expected to receive buffer size')
        return struct.unpack("i", data)[0]

    def flush(self):
        if len(self.buffer)>0:
            self.__clientSocket.sendall(self.buffer)
        self.buffer = ''

    def __sendall(self, s):
        self.buffer = self.buffer + s

    def send(self,s):
        try:
            if (not self.isConnected()):
                raise Exception('Socket is not connected')
            data = s.pickle()
            self.__sendint(len(data))
            self.__sendall(data)
        except Exception, e:
            self.disconnect()
            raise e

    def sendEOC(self):
        self.send(Command(CommandAction.EOC, time()))#send our system time. can be used for ping

    def receive(self):
        if (not self.isConnected()):
            raise Exception('Socket Error. Not Connected')
        try:
            #first receive the size of packet
            buffsize = self.__recvint()
            #now receive the actual data
            data = self.__recv(buffsize)

            if not data:
                raise Exception('No data to receive')

            command = Command.unpickle(data)
        except Exception, e:
            self.disconnect()
            command = Command(CommandAction.Invalid, None)
            raise e
        #finally?
        return command

    def isConnected(self):
        return self.__connected

    def setClientSocket(self, clientSocket):
        self.__clientSocket = clientSocket
        self.__connected = True #assume its connected
```

Comment: Hi Mark, could you please provide an example of how you made it work ? I am in the exact same position: I am trying to send a lengthy string from the server to the client, but the client receives just a small portion of it. It would be very helpful if you demonstrated this.

Comment: @user690182 here's the example (the class I created)